# subfloat caption adjustment does not work

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

I want to remove the extra margin in front of the second subcaption (the yellow part).
How can I achieve this?

[image]

My current code is as follows.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand\mycaption[2]{\caption{\textbf{#1}\newline\footnotesize#2}}
\captionsetup{font=small, labelfont=bf, singlelinecheck=false, tableposition=bottom, justification=justified}
\begin{document}

% test 
\begin{figure}[h]
\captionsetup[subfloat]{farskip=1pt, captionskip=0pt} %<--I thought it does the job...
\centering
\captionsetup{width=0.7\linewidth}
\subfloat[First figure]
{%
    \label{fig1}%
    \includegraphics[clip,width=0.85\columnwidth]{myfig1.png} }
    \vfill 
\subfloat[Second figure]
{%
    \label{fig2}%
    \includegraphics[clip,width=0.85\columnwidth]{myfig2.png} }
\mycaption{Test}{Explanation blah blah...}
\label{figExamples}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**NOTE**

It might be figure specific issue, so I am attaching two images here for your advice.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your sample code does *not* produce a gap between a subfigure's graphs and capition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second figure has some blank space underneath.

Use `trim={<left> <lower> <right> <upper>}`

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand\mycaption[2]{\caption{\textbf{#1}\newline\footnotesize#2}}
\captionsetup{font=small, labelfont=bf, singlelinecheck=false, tableposition=bottom, justification=justified}
\begin{document}
    
    % test 
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \captionsetup[subfloat]{farskip=1pt, captionskip=0pt} %<--I thought it does the job...
        \centering
        \captionsetup{width=0.7\linewidth}
        \subfloat[First figure]
        {%
            \label{fig1}%
            \includegraphics[clip,width=0.85\columnwidth]{myfig1.png} } 
        \vfill 
        \subfloat[Second figure]
        {%
            \label{fig2}%
            \includegraphics[trim={ 0pt 25pt 0pt 0pt}, clip,width=0.85\columnwidth]{myfig2.png} }% changed <<<<<<
        \mycaption{Test}{Explanation blah blah...}
        \label{figExamples}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You answered what I was exactly looking for. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I cant reproduce your problem. It may be, that the second image contain some white space below images. This you can check by adding `fbox` around image, for example:

```
\subfloat[Second figure \label{fig2}]
{\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-duck}} }
\caption[Test]{ Test\\
                \footnotesize
                Explanation \lipsum*[66]}
```

White space you can remove by samo image processing tool or by use of `trim` option of `graphicx` package.

Off-topic:

It is not entirely clear, why you define `\mycaption`. If you like to differentiate text in list of figures (LoF) from caption text at figure, you should use

```
\caption[<text in LoF>]{Text at figure}
```

For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\captionsetup{font=small,
              labelfont=bf,
              justification=justified,
              singlelinecheck=false,
              }
% changed page share for floats and text 
 \renewcommand{\topfraction}{.95}
 \renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{.85}
 \renewcommand{\textfraction}{.05}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\subfloat[First figure  \label{fig1}]
{\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-duck} }

\bigskip
\subfloat[Second figure \label{fig2}]
{\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-duck} }
\caption[Test]{ Test.\\
                \footnotesize
                Explanation \lipsum*[66]}
\label{figExamples}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the caption setup. I thought it would be handy to define mycaption globally so that I can use the same set-up repeatedly in a large project. But you are right, there is no need to do so if it can be done as you showed.